# solving equation using ode45 in matlab

Tags: matlab, ode45

I have this equation `B1*(phi) + B2*(d(phi)/ds) -B3(d^2(phi)/ds^2) = 0`. here `B1`, `B2`, `B3` are 4D matrices. the initial condition are `phi = 0` at `s = 0` and `d(phi)/ds = 0` at `s = 0`.

```
% Define the anonymous function for the equation
equation = @(s, phi_dphi) [phi_dphi(2); -B1.*phi_dphi(1) + B2.*phi_dphi(2) - B3.*(phi_dphi(2).^2)];

% Define the initial conditions
phi0 = [0;0;0;0]; % Initial condition for phi
dphi_ds0 = [0;0;0;0]; % Initial condition for d(phi)/ds

% Set the options for ode45 (optional)
options = odeset('RelTol', 1e-6, 'AbsTol', 1e-6);

% Solve the equation using ode45
[t, phi_dphi] = ode45(equation, [S_0, S_L], [phi0; dphi_ds0], options);

% Extract the solution for phi and d(phi)/ds
phi = phi_dphi(:, 1);
dphi_ds = phi_dphi(:, 2);

% Display the results
disp('Solution:')
disp('---------')
disp('s phi d(phi)/ds')
disp([t, phi, dphi_ds]);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What do you expect us to do? You forgot to ask a question here. Also do add the error message you mention. We're not clairvoyant. See [mre] and [edit] the question.

Comment: What does it mean for B1, B2, and B3 to be 4D matrices with what appears to be a scalar phi variable differential equation? This doesn't make any sense to me. Normally you would solve your DE for the highest order derivative variable and go from there, but if the B's are 4D matrices this doesn't make sense. Maybe post an image of the differential equation you are solving and we can help you get started.